# What is Matlab "clearvars -except" equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, loops, except

I want to clear all variables in my code except the loop index after every iteration. for example

```
for i=1:20
c= i+20; 
save c;
clearvars -except i
end
```

How do I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to define a function, and then only return the variables you want to keep.  In Python, variables that are defined within the scope of a function are removed when the function is done executing.

```py
def my_for(i):
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        c = j + 20
    return i
```

Comment: the problem is that. i work with dictionaries and pickle. and i have a nested 2 loops. so after the first loop finishes and have saved all variables to pickle. i want to clear to avoid any problems.